# .Net Web API and Autofac Resolve Parameter Binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am using Autofac for DI with a .Net Web API project. Some of the parameters to controller action are bound using HttpParameterBinding. I know these bound parameters are in HTTPActionContext object.

One of the dependency requires a bound parameter to be resolved. Will I be able to resolve the HTTPActionContext to access the parameter?

I tried debugging, seems like parameter binding occurs only after dependencies are resolved, at least in my case.